# Where do I set up a comment object?

Tags: ember.js

I have a template `templates/post.hbs` with this content:

```
<h2>{{title}}</h2>
<div>
  {{#link-to 'post.edit' this}}Edit{{/link-to}}
  <a {{action 'destroy'}}>Destroy</a>
</div>
{{text}}


{{ render 'comments/new' }}

<h3>Comments</h3> 

{{#each comments}}
  <strong>{{author}}</strong>
  {{text}}
{{/each}}
```

The `comments/new` form near the bottom there has content like this:

```
<h3>Leave a comment</h3>
<form>
  <p class='input-group'>
    <label for='text'>Text</label><br>
    {{textarea value=text class="form-control" rows="10" cols="50"}}
  </p>
  <input type='button' value='Add Comment' class='btn btn-primary' {{action 'save' this}}>
</form>
```

Where and how do I set up a `Blorgh.Comment` object to be used in this form? Does it go into the `PostRoute` or the `CommentsNewController`? If so, what's the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can accomplish this, though I'd suggest one of the following:

1. Set the model in `CommentsNewController`'s `init` method. It would look something like this:

   ```
   App.CommentsNewController = ObjectController.extend({
     init: function() {
       this.set('model', App.Comment.create());
     }
   });
   ```
2. Bind the new comment to a controller property in `PostRoute` and then pass it to the render helper, like so:

   ```
   {{render 'comments/new' comment_object }}
   ```

You could even maybe use an outlet instead and do it all in `PostRoute#setupController`.